# Using Tortoise SVN diff in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, tfs, tortoisesvn, diff

I want to use Tortoise SVN diff utility with TFS. I know how to configure user tools in TFS. What I need is installer for Tortoise SVN diff utility. I think I need to install full Tortoise SVN to get SVN diff tool, is there a standalone version of this tool available for download?

I know various other diff tools are available like winMerge etc. but I am very much familiar with tortoise svn diff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The TSVN diff tools are available separately.
See the [download page](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads), scroll down to "Tools".

Or directly from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/files/Tools/).

Answer (score 32):

If you want to use [Tortoise Merge](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/TortoiseMerge.html) with TFS. You need to install [Tortoise SVN](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/files/1.6.15/Application/TortoiseSVN-1.6.15.21042-x64-svn-1.6.16.msi/download).

And then follow the steps [here](http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2008/07/05/Rediscovering-Three-pane-Merging-with-TortoiseMerge-and-Team-Foundation-Server/)

> Compare  Command: `C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseMerge.exe`
>   Arguments:
>   `/base:%1 /mine:%2 /basename:%6 /minename:%7`
>
> Merge 
>   Command: `C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseMerge.exe`
>   Arguments: `/base:%3 /mine:%2 /theirs:%1 /basename:%8 /minename:%7 /theirsname:%6 /merged:%4 /mergedname:%9`

Comment: Is there another step to this? I have the same set up however when I try to merge it tells me that Merge Target is not found. See my question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/9313574/37759