# Using TortoiseMerge with Visual Studio and TFS - Merge Target (not found)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs, tortoisesvn

I want to set up TortoiseMerge as a merge tool in Visual Studio 2010. I'm using TFS for source control. In Visual Studio I configured TortoiseMerge to be a merge tool and [gave it parameters specified here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmanning/archive/2006/02/20/diff-merge-configuration-in-team-foundation-common-command-and-argument-values.aspx) `/base:%3 /mine:%2 /theirs:%1 /basename:%8 /minename:%7 /theirsname:%6 /merged:%4 /mergedname:%9`

[image]

When I try to merge, the Merge Target says that it is not found. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Based on the following page you are doing it right.  I used this page to setup Beyond Compare for compare/merge and love it.  If you cannot get Tortoise to work perhaps try Beyond Compare.  It isn't free but its a great product. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmanning/archive/2006/02/20/diff-merge-configuration-in-team-foundation-common-command-and-argument-values.aspx

Comment: I have been using TortoiseMerge for years and that message always appears during merge. Not sure why, but merging works, saving the file works (it's considered you've done the merge) and most importantly VS (or TF.EXE) picks up the merged file and asks you for confirmation when you're done. Enjoy it :-)

Comment: @Jonno can you put your comment as an answer so we can vote for it (and so it be marked as an answer  if it's helpful)

Answer (score 5):

I have been using TortoiseMerge for years and that message always appears during merge. Not sure why, but merging works, saving the file works (it's considered you've done the merge) and most importantly VS (or TF.EXE) picks up the merged file and asks you for confirmation when you're done.

Enjoy it :-)