# Duplicate file in visual studio 2013

Tags: file, visual-studio-2013, duplicates

I have mvc project in visual studio 2013 in the views folder there is a file with the same name but in duplicate ,in the source control is one file also in the file folder from windows is one file but in visual studio is duplicate , also from another client is the same when he gets the project from team foundation .
any help please ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found this answer worked for me
unload the project then edit csproject file 
find the duplicate file name with extension, you will see both remove or comment one of them it will be solved .

[Doubling file names in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660884/doubling-file-names-in-visual-studio-2012)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Searched the csproj for duplicate entries but none found. Turns out that a wildcard include had been entered into the csproj for the directory e.g. directoryWithDuplicates/**