# TortoiseMerge with Visual Studio and Ankh

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2008, tortoisemerge

I reintegrated a branch (svn) and now I have conflicting files. 
Now there are tags like ''<<<<<<< .working'' in the files. We are using the Ankh plugin. What is the command for visual studio, options, Source-Control, Subversion User Tools, External Merge Tools?

I would like to use TortoiseMerge. I found samples for TFS, but not for SVN Ankh.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is concrete problem? How to resolve a conflict with ankh?

Comment: Ok, I try to be more specific. In Visual Studio, I have to set the command to start the mergetool. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959116/using-tortoise-svn-diff-in-tfs

Comment: The link above is for TFS? How is the startup command for ankh?
For TFS it is something like Merge Command: C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseMerge.exe Arguments: /base:%3 /mine:%2 /theirs:%1 /basename:%8 /minename:%7 /theirsname:%6 /merged:%4 /mergedname:%9